# Remove table row from HTML text

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove a table row using jQuery but I can't see were I am going wrong with this as I can't remove it.

```
url: 'http://www.ncefl.org.uk/teams/hullunited/matches/2015/',
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
  var extra = '#singlecolumn form #middle div table tr td i';
  var trrem = $(res.responseText).find(extra).closest('tr').remove();
  $('.inBx').html(res.responseText);
}
```

As above I am finding the `<i>` element in a table row, which is the row I would like to completely remove.

```
<div class="six columns">
            <h5 class="title03">Upcoming Matches</h5>
            <div class="inBx">
                <div class="loader"></div>
                <div class="matchBx">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns next_team">
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns next_match">
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns next_away_team">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row midTxt nxtmtchdate">
                </div>
                <table class="striped next_matches_block">
                </table>
                <p id="nextfa" class="fa"></p>
            </div>
            <a href="/fixtures-and-results" class="seebtn">See All Fixtures</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you can provide some html too.

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: The selector can be (at least) shortened to `#middle div table tr td i` as IDs are unique.

Comment: @Reeno: *Unless* they want not to remove it if it isn't a descendant of `#singlecolumn`.

Comment: whats in res.responseText ? provide some code

Comment: Question edited and improved above where I am getting the HTML from.

Answer (score 2):

That won't modify `responseText`; it will only modify the temporary jQuery object you create and then throw away.

If you want to keep a copy of the modified document fragment, do so:

```
var extra = '#singlecolumn form #middle div table tr td i';
var jres = $(res.responseText); 
var trrem = jres.find(extra).closest('tr').remove();

$('.inBx').empty().append(jres);
```

```js
var res = {
  responseText: '<div> <div id="singlecolumn"> <form action=""> <div id="middle"> <div> <table>' +
    '<tr> <td><i>italic</i></td> </tr> ' +
    '<tr> <td>not</td> </tr> ' +
    '</table> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div>'
}

var extra = '#singlecolumn form #middle div table tr td i';
var jres = $(res.responseText);
var trrem = jres.find(extra).closest('tr').remove();

$(document.body).append(jres);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```